# Loading component asynchronously in Vue.js does not work

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I am trying to replace loading [v-tooltip's](https://akryum.github.io/v-tooltip) `VPopper` component from standard loading to asynchronous loading.

**Standard loading - component loaded and working normally**

```
import { VPopover } from 'v-tooltip'

export default {
  components: {
    VPopover
  }
}
```

**Asynchronous load - component not loaded correctly**

```
export default {
  components: {
    VPopover: () => import('v-tooltip')
  },
}
```

For some reason above is not working and component is not loaded correctly. Maybe because it’s not a default export but named export in the v-tooltip Vue component?

I am using Webpack in-behind.

If I load my custom component asynchronously then it works as expected. For example this is working for me:

```
export default {
  components: {
    MyCustomComponent: () => import('@/components/MyCustomComponent.vue')
  }
}
```

Comment: The lazy module import returns a Promise with the module export, in your case an object containing the named export. Vue don't know what of the named exports should import, so, simply does nothing. Just export the component as default.

Comment: @gugadev Hmm okay I understand. It's not my component but a `v-tooltip` package component installed via `npm` and included into `package.json`. Anything else I can do or will I have to fork the package and fix this?

Comment: Just create a wrapper where import the library and export it as default: `import { SomeName } from 'v-tooltip'; export default SomeName;`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @gugadev has noted above

> The lazy module import returns a Promise with the module export, in
>   your case an object containing the named export. Vue don't know what
>   of the named exports should import, so, simply does nothing.

I found this solution that works

```
export default {
  components: {
    VPopover: () => import('v-tooltip').then(m => m.VPopover)
  }
}
```